# Count arrays with GCD as D

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, divisibility

Given N ,I need to count the number of array of integers which satisfy the following conditions :

```
1. Array must contain N elements.
2. Each element in array must be less than given number M.
3. Greatest common divisor of all its elements is equal to a given integer D.
```

I need to count such arrays for all D between L to R(including L and R).It means $D=L,L+1,L+2....R$.

Example : Let $ N=5 , M=5 ,L=4 $ and $R=5 $ then here answer is $2$.

How to find it for given $N,M,L$ and $R$.Please help

Can their be direct formula for this problem ? Or is their some proper way or algorithm to do it .

Comment: If you can count the number of pairs $(a,b)$ with $1\le a\le M$, $1\le b\le M$, and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, you'll have some idea of what you're up against, even in the simplest case.

Comment: Am I right to think that the $\Phi$ function is required?

Comment: @shardulc What phi function ? I didn't get you

Comment: @GerryMyerson And how to count such pairs.Please explain how it will solve this problem

Comment: Do you have some boundaries in N,M,L,R?

Comment: @Phicar 1 ≤ N, M ≤ 10^7 AND  1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ M . Also I know that answer can be large so I want it modulo 10^9 + 7

Comment: Ah, so it's a problem from an ongoing contest, then?

Comment: Seems it was also posted to, but removed from, another site, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335768/count-arrays-with-given-gcd --- was that you, 3185653?